# Вопрос по поводу реднеринга в JSF <f:ajax

Tags: java, ajax, веб-программирование, jsf, glassfish

Код, который нужно обновить :

```
      <div id="booksContent">
            <ui:repeat value="#{booksList.returnList()}" var="b">
                <div class="media col-lg-6" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 20px;">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <img src="#{b.imgLink}" class="media-object" style="width:150px"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">#{b.name}</h4> 
                        <br/>
                        <h5 class="media-heading">Автор:     #{b.author}</h5>
                        <h5 class="media-heading">Жанр:   #{b.genreName}</h5>
                        <h5 class="media-heading">Дата выхода: #{b.date}</h5>
                        <br/>
                        <p>#{b.shortDescription}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </ui:repeat> 
                </div>
```

Код , который будет обновлять :

```
      <ui:composition>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <h:form>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <h:commandLink><li class="list-group-item">Все</li>
                        <f:param name="genre_id" value=""></f:param>
                        <f:param name="genre_name" value=""></f:param>                            
                        <f:ajax event="click" render=":booksContent" listener="#{booksList.retList(g.id,g.name)}"/>
                    </h:commandLink>
                <ui:repeat value="#{genreList.formArrayList()}" var="g">
                    <h:commandLink>
                        <li class="list-group-item">#{g.name}
                        <f:ajax event="click" render=":booksContent"  listener="#{booksList.retList(g.id,g.name)}"/>
                        </li>
                    </h:commandLink>
                    </ui:repeat>
              </ul>
             </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:composition>
```

Вопрос : 
Переменная , которая отображается в коде обновляется при аякс запросе , но код показа не обновляется. Подскажите , пожст пожст пожст

Comment: Попробуй вместо `<div id='booksContent'>` использовать `<h:panelGroup id='booksContent' layout='bock'>`

Comment: попробую , спасибо

Comment: Заработало , спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

JSF ajax ищет обновляемые компоненты по jsf component tree а не через html DOM, поэтому в ajax должны фигурировать только элементы jsf component tree.